# Using a method both inside a class and outside - python

Tags: python, class

So I have a function that, so far, I have had as a method inside a class.
 Turns out now I want to use it without making an instance of the class.

What is the best way of doing this without having to massively change the code?

Example codes follow:

Before:

```
class A(object):
 def method1(self, input):
  return input*3 + 7
 def method2(self, input):
  return self.method1(input) + 4
```

Basically I want to take `method1` out of the class so that i can use it without making an instance of `A`, but also do not want change `self.method1` to `method1` everywhere.

My idea:

```
def method1(input):
 return input*3 + 7

class A(object):
 def __init__(self):
  self.method1 = method1
 def method2(self, input):
  return self.method1(input) + 4
```

--

Is this bad practice? 
 How else could one call a method from inside a class? Or alternatively how can a class incorporate methods methods outside it?

Comment: Note that `input` is a python built-in, you might want to rename the variable so you don't blast over the builtin.

Comment: also be aware that if your `self.method1 = method1` is in `def __init__` it will execute everytime you create an instance

Comment: Isn’t that what I want? To set method1 in the class equal to methid1 outside the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def method1(input):
 return input*3 + 7

class A(object):
    def method1(self, input):
        return method1(input)

    def method2(self, input):
        return self.method1(input) + 4
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because of the `self` parameter. Instead, define it like this:

```
class A(object):
    def method1(self, input):
        return method1(input)
```

Comment: Sorry but for me it works? Is it bad to put it in the init?

Comment: I'm so sorry... yes. It should work. I just got confused - what your code does is not create an instance method (that implies a `self` parameter), but just stores a function reference. I guess you really can do this. As to whether it is a good idea... If you have an IDE like PyCharm or use a refactoring tool (is bicycle repair man still a thing?) you should be able to move the method to a function and have the calls all updated automatically - that might be a cleaner approach...

Answer (score 0):

This is called a **static method** in order to do this, your function can not contain `(self)`

```
class A(object):

    def method_one(variable):
        return variable * 3 + 7

    def method_two(self, variable):
        return self.method_one(variable) + 4

print(A.method_one(10))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 method_out.py 
> 37
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Turn into a staticmethod the method you don't need or don't want an instance of its class.
The ideia would be like the following:

```
>>> class A:
    @staticmethod
    def m(value):
        return value*3+7
    def sum(self, value):
        return self.m(value) + 4


>>> a = A()
>>> a.sum(4)
23
>>> 4+A.m(4)
23
>>>
```

Notice the difference from a normal method to the static one. On the static one you ommit the self parameter, thus meaning you don't need an instance of its class to use that static method.